# pq: permission denied for table users while connecting to postgresql database

Tags: database, postgresql, go, permission-denied

I got problems, while I connect to database in Go.

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var DB *sql.DB

func init() {
    var err error

    connStr := "postgres://{my-user}@localhost:5432/{name-of-my-database}?sslmode=disable"
    DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connStr)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // checks if we are connected to db
    if err = DB.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("The database is connected")

    _, err = DB.Exec("INSERT INTO users (username, email, passwordhash) VALUES ('a', 'a', 'a');")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When I try to make changes to database I receive error that I am missing permission, however user, which is connected to database is the owner of it and has all privileges.

Comment: Please show the actual error message, not your interpretation of it.